# Converting a tcsh alias into zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, alias, tcsh

I had a `tcsh` alias as follows:

```
alias cdd 'cd `dirname \!*`'
```

I use this to change the directory to the one containing a certain file.

For instance,

```
cdd /Users/myself/Document/Folder/File.pdf
```

would change the directory to `/Users/myself/Document/Folder/`.

How could I "convert it" to the `zsh` shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `zsh` shell, you could define a shell function that changes the working directory to the parent directory of the first argument (the trailing `:h` in the code below removes the last pathname component from a pathname stored in a variable, and `$1` is the first argument to the function):

```bash
cdd () cd -- $1:h
```

Or, you could use a more portable shell function (would work in any `sh`-like shell, including both `zsh` and `bash`):

```bash
cdd () { cd -- "$(dirname -- "$1")"; }
```

This uses portable shell function syntax and uses `dirname` just like your `tcsh` alias does.  The occurrences of double dash in both functions protects against interpreting the argument as an option if it starts with a dash.

Both functions above would change to the current directory (i.e. do pretty much nothing) if given no argument.

I suggest using shell functions because aliases don't take arguments in non-`tcsh` shells. You can therefore not examine the pathname in "the first argument to the alias" to determine its parent directory.